# Graphical issue with spinner control in Android

Tags: android, spinner, scrollview, tablelayout

My first (old) Android app ([Suspension Calculator](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.synformation.android.forzadroid)) is showing a problem I cannot find a solution for: the spinner control on *some* spinners is showing transparent lines in unwanted places. The pattern is this: every other spinner is having this problem, starting with the first spinner control. So while spinners 2, 4, 6, ... have no unwanted lines, spinners 1, 3, 5, ... have them.

The following image (link below) shows the spinner in selected state first, and in unselected state after the red separator. In selected state, the transparent line is at baseline height for the entire control *except* some places where the button text can be. It's a little different in unselected state.

I cannot provide an image directly:

> [...] as a spam prevention mechanism, new
>   users aren't allowed to post images.

But I can give you a link:

[Screenshot that illustrated the graphical spinner problem](http://blog.synformation.com/android/spinner-problem.png)

The XML file under `res/layout` looks like this:

```
<ScrollView ...>
    <TableLayout ...>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/units"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
            />
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/unit_spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            />
        </TableRow>
        ...
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I see this problem at least since Froyo (Android 2.2). In earlier versions (at least Android 1.6), it wasn't there. It's not there in the Graphical Layout editor in Eclipse, but I see it running the application on the phone and in the emulator - that's at least consistent and hints to a problem I'm causing by not doing things right ;-).

Comment: Are you using custom drawables in these buttons?

Comment: No, everything is plain standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I can reproduce this behavior on Android 2.3. Not possible on Android 2.2 and lower.

It' doesn't matter if you place the Spinner in a TableLayout or RelativeLayout. Same problem there..

Only solution to get ride of the lines was to put a 1px-View between the spinner:

```
<Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinnerDriver"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_below="@id/driverDesc" />

<View android:id="@+id/helper" android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_below="@id/spinnerDriver" />

<Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinnerDriver1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_below="@id/helper" />
```

This is actually a very, very, very...  ugly solution but it works for me...

Comment: Your idea works, but I've to put the View *before* the Spinner in order to work (in fact before every Spinner). If I put two Views before the Spinner, the effect is back. So it seems the problem affects every other component, starting with 1, then 3, 5, ... The problem now sounds like an Android 2.3 bug to me.

Comment: Next observation: when I'm at the bottom of the TableLayout and the scrolling from the ScrollView kicks in (scrolling down), the lines are back. They go away if I'm scrolling up again. Strange ...

Comment: hmm.. no idea.. sounds like an android bug as it worked in previous versions.. Should I get any further informations about that I'll post it here...