# Creating a high quality Android user interface

Tags: android

I have created an Android app using the standard controls available. It seems that most apps on the market have their own set of controls. It generally looks much better that the standard controls. How do I create better looking control? Can I just apply a theme or should I overwrite the onDraw method? For instance, there is a problem with the default android spinner control [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003583/graphical-problem-with-spinner-control-in-android) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding custom images is the best way to have more eye-catching GUI, use colorful & meaningful images to your application to appeal users. Custom theme's and styles are helpful too.....

Answer (score 2):

You can apply different [themes and styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) on the one hand or work with 9patch-drawables - have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) for details and examples