# Android - Thin transparent line running through spinners, device specific?

Tags: android, spinner

[image: Notice the white lines under the arrows]

Mysterious transparent lines are showing up in our spinners on certain devices.  I've seen this before but there must be a way to get rid of them... I'm assuming it's something janky with the 9-patch used for the graphic.

Anyone have any advice?  Layout snippet below:

```
<TableRow>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerPostPage"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

            </TableRow>
```

UPDATE: Full layout below - no styling external to this layout is used:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#008db9"  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/create_a_craze"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/save" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/layoutHeader" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutBody"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/layoutHeader"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewCrazeTitleLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="#a1a0a3"
                        android:text="@string/craze_title_label" />

                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/editTextCrazeTitle"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:hint="@string/craze_title"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonAddImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/add_image" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageViewThumbnailOne"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="75dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_margin="2dp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageViewThumbnailTwo"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="75dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_margin="2dp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageViewThumbnailThree"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="75dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_margin="2dp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <CheckBox 
                        android:id="@+id/checkBoxShareLocation"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:textColor="#a1a0a3"
                        android:text="@string/share_location_map"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewPostToLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="#a1a0a3"
                        android:text="@string/post_title_label" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerPostOptions"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerPostPage"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_column="1" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/textViewShareCrazeLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="#a1a0a3"
                        android:text="@string/share_craze_label" />

                    <Spinner 
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerPrivacySettings"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_column="1" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewCrazeDescriptionLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#a1a0a3"
                        android:text="@string/craze_description_label" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/editTextCrazeDescription"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/layoutBody"
                android:minLines="3"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does the line move with the spinner [item], or does it stay in its relative location?

Comment: I didn't think of it till you asked but it's not actually a white line - it's just the color of the background, as if something is getting clipped.  I'd need to test on a device the has this issue to find out if it's absolute or relative (follows) the spinner in the layou.

Comment: Seen it occurring on Android 2.2.2, on a Droid X, during in-house testing.  Works fine on other 2.2.X and 2.3.X devices.  Client is also experiencing, still need to get his device specifics.

Comment: Related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003583/graphical-problem-with-spinner-control-in-android

Comment: @slukian, I may be mistaken - the Droid X may actually be 2.1.X, I'll check.  Getting info from client now...

Comment: @LadaRaider, that's exactly the same thing we're experiencing.  It isn't a specific color of the line, it's just transparent clipping on the spinner.  Maybe their solution will work, not gonna know until Monday.